# keras concatenate along dimension 0 valueerror

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, concatenation, valueerror

So I am trying to concatenate two keras tensors:

```
a = keras.layers.Input(shape=[5,], dtype='float', name='a')
b = keras.layers.Input(shape=[5,], dtype='float', name='b')
s = keras.layers.concatenate([a, b], axis=0)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[a, b], outputs=s)

aa = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1]])
bb = np.array([[3,3,3,3,3]])

cc = model.predict({'a':aa, 'b':bb})
```

what i got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File"D:\Anaconda3\envs\kerase\lib\sitepackages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-64-ddbf264b3bdb>", line 50, in <module>
cc = model.predict({'a':aa, 'b':bb})
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\kerase\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1713, in predict
verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\kerase\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1278, in _predict_loop
outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out
```

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,5) into shape (1,5)

I don't understand. Am I not using the 'axis' parameter properly? With axis=-1 the tensors would got correctly concatenated along the last dimension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ok, 2 rank-1 tensors can only be concatenated in one possible way. and this works:

```
a = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1, 5], dtype='float', name='a')
b = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1, 5], dtype='float', name='b')
s = keras.layers.concatenate([a, b], axis=-2)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[a, b], outputs=s)

aa = np.array([[[1,1,1,1,1]]])
bb = np.array([[[3,3,3,3,3]]])

cc = model.predict({'a':aa, 'b':bb})
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras expects the output batch_size to be the same as the input batch_size.
The batch_size is always the first dimension which is 1 in this case.

So a common strategy is to use tf.expand_dims to add the first dimension of 1 as the batch_size. Here is the modified code which will work.

```
a = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1, 5], dtype='float', name='a')
b = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1, 5], dtype='float', name='b')
s = keras.layers.concatenate([a, b], axis=-2)
f = tf.expand_dims(concated, axis=0)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[a, b], outputs=f)

aa = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1]])
bb = np.array([[3,3,3,3,3]])

cc = model.predict({'a':aa, 'b':bb})
```